# Debian 9: cannot start supervisor after a fresh install

Tags: debian, supervisord

### Distro

```
$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Debian
Description:    Debian GNU/Linux 9.11 (stretch)
Release:        9.11
Codename:       stretch
```

### How I installed `supervisor`

```
$ sudo apt install supervisor
Lettura elenco dei pacchetti... Fatto
Generazione albero delle dipendenze
Lettura informazioni sullo stato... Fatto
Pacchetti suggeriti:
  supervisor-doc
I seguenti pacchetti NUOVI saranno installati:
  supervisor
0 aggiornati, 1 installati, 0 da rimuovere e 0 non aggiornati.
È necessario scaricare 280 kB di archivi.
Dopo quest'operazione, verranno occupati 1.452 kB di spazio su disco.
Scaricamento di:1 http://ftp.it.debian.org/debian stretch/main amd64 supervisor all 3.3.1-1+deb9u1 [280 kB]
Recuperati 280 kB in 0s (3.729 kB/s)
Selezionato il pacchetto supervisor non precedentemente selezionato.
(Lettura del database... 73752 file e directory attualmente installati.)
Preparativi per estrarre .../supervisor_3.3.1-1+deb9u1_all.deb...
Estrazione di supervisor (3.3.1-1+deb9u1)...
Configurazione di supervisor (3.3.1-1+deb9u1)...
Elaborazione dei trigger per systemd (232-25+deb9u12)...
Elaborazione dei trigger per man-db (2.7.6.1-2)...
```

I created `/etc/supervisor/conf.d/project_worker.conf

```
[program:project-worker]
process_name=%(program_name)s_%(process_num)02d
command=php /var/www/html/project/artisan queue:work redis --sleep=3 --tries=10 --delay=15
autostart=true
autorestart=true
user=realtebo
numprocs=1
redirect_stderr=true
stdout_logfile=/var/www/html/project/storage/logs/master_laravel_worker.log
```

### The problems

Tryed to read config

```
$ sudo supervisorctl reread
error: <class 'socket.error'>, [Errno 2] No such file or directory: file: /usr/lib/python2.7/socket.py line: 228
```

Tried to reload

```
$ sudo supervisorctl reload
error: <class 'socket.error'>, [Errno 2] No such file or directory: file: /usr/lib/python2.7/socket.py line: 228
```

Tried to force start anyway

```
$ sudo supervisorctl start
unix:///var/run/supervisor.sock no such file
```

I am also not able to ask supervisor its own version

```
$ sudo supervisorctl version
unix:///var/run/supervisor.sock no such file
```

### What I tried

Tried to stop/start service: error is still here

```
$ sudo service supervisor stop
$ sudo service supervisor start
$ sudo supervisorctl version
unix:///var/run/supervisor.sock no such file
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've not found the reason, but I resolved in the hardest way

```
sudo apt purge supervisor
sudo reboot
```

> Note: I ended to reboot after purge because purge/reinstall was not working.

After then, reinstalled, recreated `the conf.d/` files.

All works now.

Probably the source cause was a recent system upgrade, but I'm not sure.

Sorry to say I've not a better solution and also I've not an explanation.